# Adicionar ao Arquivo de texto Usando pascal

Tags: pascal, txt

Eu fiz esse algoritmo em Pascal que alimenta informação numérica em um arquivo de texto.

```
program Pascal; 
var
  i:integer;
  Vect:array[1..1001] of integer; 
  Myfile: text;
begin 
  i:=1;
  for i:=1 to 999 do 
    vect[i]:=i+1; 
  Assign(Myfile, 'Myfile.txt');
  Rewrite(MyFile);
  for i:=1 to 999 do
  begin 
    WriteLn(vect[i]);
    WriteLn(Myfile, vect[i]); 
  End;
  Close(Myfile); 
  ReadLn;
End.
```

Eu precisava de uma ideia para um outro programa que, assim que esse arquivo de texto fosse alimentado, automaticamente o programa iria *add* a data atual a cada linha que fosse inserida.

Eu não estou pedindo o código ou o programa já elaborado. Apenas de uma ideia de como usar o **Assign**, Por exemplo, ou talvez usando um arquivo **.bat**. Não sei.

Estou aprendendo lógica de programação mas não tenho conhecimento de algumas ferramentas de cada linguagem, como nesse caso, uma interação entre arquivos ou programas.

Comment: Tu quer que junto de cada número seja inserido do lado a hora em que está sendo inserido?

Comment: Isso. A cada N caracteres ou N linhas (tanto faz) seja inserido a data e hora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que todo elemento seja impresso a data junto, você vai precisar concatenar(juntar o texto). No pascal isso é feito com o `+`.

Para inserir a data você pode usar `DateTimeToStr(Now)`.

Para executar alguma coisa a cada X iterações, você pode usar o operador `mod`. Ele é o operador de resto de uma divisão. Usando `if (X mod Y = 0)` significa que vai executar o código dentro do `if` a cada `Y` iterações. (ou melhor dizendo, sempre que `X` for um múltiplo de `Y`)

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o código abaixo atende a sua demanda, a unit indicada pelo companheiro so atenderia a sua necessidade se você trabalhar com freepascal, este código eu fiz com pascalzim.

A saída gerada no prompt e salva no arquivo segue o seguinte formato:

1 - 0:16:56 - S bado, 26/Marco/2016.

905 - 0:18:32 - S bado, 26/Marco/2016.

1000 - 0:18:42 - S bado, 26/Marco/2016.

O delay foi incluído apenas para dar um espaço de tempo entre os registros para assim ser constatado que o horário foi colocado corretamente.

```
program ArquivoNumDate; 
const
    DiaDaSemana: array[0..6] of string ('Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado');
    MesDoAno: array[1..12] of string=('Janeiro','Fevereiro','Marco','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro');

var
   i:integer;
   Vect:array[0..1001] of integer; 
   Arquivo: text;
   dia, mes, ano, diaSemana: integer;
   hora, minuto, segundo, msegundo: integer;

begin       

   for i := 0 to 999 do 
       vect[i]:= i + 1; 

   Assign(Arquivo, 'Arquivo.txt');
   Rewrite(Arquivo);

   for i := 0 to 999 do
   begin           
      delay(100);
      GetDate(ano, mes, dia, diaSemana);
      GetTime(hora, minuto, segundo, msegundo);   
      WriteLn(vect[i],' - ', hora,':', minuto,':', segundo, ' - ', DiaDaSemana[diaSemana],', ',dia,'/',MesDoAno[mes],'/',ano,'.');
      WriteLn(Arquivo, vect[i],' - ', hora,':', minuto,':', segundo, ' - ', DiaDaSemana[diaSemana],', ',dia,'/',MesDoAno[mes],'/',ano,'.');
   End;

   Close(Arquivo); 
   ReadLn;

End.
```